# Shared Application Configuration using Project Settings Configuration with Enterprise Library

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I'm trying to use Enterprise Library Configuration Merge feature, but it doesn't seem to work.

I Have 3 projects: DLL1, EXE1 and EXE2.

The DLL project is using the Settings configuration style (ie. DLL1Namespace.Properties.Settings.Default) - it adds the configuration section in the "applicationSettings" sectionGroup.

ConfigSections:

```
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <section name="DLL1Namepsace.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

applicationSettings:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <DLL1Namepsace.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Setting1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Value1</value>
      </setting>
    <DLL1Namepsace.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a shared config file for both of the EXE's that is holding the DLL application settings. Enterprise Library is supposed to have this [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953193%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) but I can't find a way to configure it. I've tried parent sections, redirecting sections, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated 5/26/2011**
This scenario of using the .NET Configuration API  directly is not supported by EntLib. To benefit from the configuration extensions  provided by EntLib (including merging and redirection), you must use EntLib’s configuration API.

The **Configuration Sources Lab** from the [Enterprise Library Hands-On Lab Set](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f8cd377-5522-4f45-a024-44a6ca5111ec) illustrates that.

Comment: Could you please post a working sample? The labs are just for enterprise library specific sections (at least this is the only thing that is working on my machine).

Comment: Bogdan, updated my answer. In your scenario, you cannot benefit from the merging and redirection features of EntLib.